# SVG point animation - works great in Chrome, but nothing else

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

For a project, I need to create a set of masked images connected to eachother by a single point on each image, and the position of that point is animated randomly (within a restricted range) on scroll.

I have managed to get this working well in Chrome, however Firefox is very buggy and Safari doesn't like the mask at all, let alone the animation. Don't even get me started on Edge/IE11. Any way around this?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/wickywills/pen/eVRPeW)

**HTML**

```
<div class="c-nodes-bg c-nodes-bg--set-of-3">
        <img id="nodes-bg-3i-1" width="100%" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1500x2800" style="clip-path: url(&quot;#clipPolygon&quot;);" class="moving">
        <img id="nodes-bg-3i-2" width="100%" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1500x2800" style="clip-path: url(&quot;#clipPolygon2&quot;);" class="moving">
        <img id="nodes-bg-3i-3" width="100%" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1500x2800" style="clip-path: url(&quot;#clipPolygon3&quot;);" class="moving">
    </div>
    <svg width="0" height="0" >
        <clipPath id="clipPolygon" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <polygon id="poly1" points="0.3 0.35,1 0.28,1 0, 0.6 0">
                <animate id="poly1Anim" attributeName="points" dur="600ms" to="" fill="freeze" />
            </polygon>
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="clipPolygon2" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <polygon id="poly2" points="0.0 0.26, 0.3 0.35, 0.6 0.7, 0.0 0.70">
                <animate id="poly2Anim" attributeName="points" dur="600ms" to="" fill="freeze" />
            </polygon>
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="clipPolygon3" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <polygon id="poly3" points="0.3 1, 1 1, 1 0.7, 0.6 0.7">
                <animate id="poly3Anim" attributeName="points" dur="600ms" to="" fill="freeze" />
            </polygon>
        </clipPath>
    </svg>
```

**CSS**

```
.c-nodes-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  /**
    Since the background images are positioned absolute as they sit behind site content,
    add in a spacer to force the height of the site to be the same as the images
   */
}
.c-nodes-bg--contact #map-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vw;
}
.c-nodes-bg__spacer {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 22px);
  display: block;
}
.c-nodes-bg--set-of-3 img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.c-nodes-bg--set-of-3 img:nth-child(2), .c-nodes-bg--set-of-3 img:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
--webkit-clip-path: url("#clipPolygon");
clip-path: url("#clipPolygon");

--webkit-clip-path: url("#clipPolygon2");
clip-path: url("#clipPolygon2");

--webkit-clip-path: url("#clipPolygon3");
clip-path: url("#clipPolygon3");
```

**JS**

```
var animPoints = {

  init: function() {
    var isScrolling;
    var scrollingDone = false;

    // Init backgrounds on scroll, but wait for a period of time after scroll starts before init
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function ( event ) {
      window.clearTimeout( isScrolling );
      isScrolling = setTimeout(function() {
        scrollingDone = true;
      }, 300);

      // Only start the animation if the previous one has finished
      if(scrollingDone === true){
        animPoints.randomiseBackgrounds();
        scrollingDone = false;
      }

    }, false);
  },

  randomiseBackgrounds: function(){
    var poly1 = document.getElementById("poly1"); // Points element within SVG
    var poly1Points = poly1.getAttribute("points"); // Points attribute containing position values
    var poly1PointsArr = poly1Points.split(","); // Convert points into array for ease of manipulation
    var poly1PointPair1Arr = poly1PointsArr[0].split(" "); // We only need the first point's coordinates
    var poly1Anim = document.getElementById("poly1Anim"); // Get the animation element within the SVG

    var poly2 = document.getElementById("poly2"); // Points element within SVG
    var poly2Points = poly2.getAttribute("points"); // Points attribute containing position values
    var poly2PointsArr = poly2Points.split(" "); // We only need the second point's coordinates
    var poly2Anim = document.getElementById("poly2Anim"); // Get the animation element within the SVG

    var poly3 = document.getElementById("poly3"); // Points element within SVG
    var poly3Points = poly3.getAttribute("points"); // Points attribute containing position values
    var poly3PointsArr = poly3Points.split(" "); // We only need the fourth point's coordinates
    var poly3Anim = document.getElementById("poly3Anim"); // Get the animation element within the SVG

    // Update X axis for point 1
    poly1PointPair1Arr[0] = Math.random() * (0.35 - 0.25) + 0.25;
    // ..and also assign that to a point on the second poly so they are connected
    poly2PointsArr[2] = poly1PointPair1Arr[0];
    poly2PointsArr[4] = Math.random() * (0.63 - 0.56) + 0.56;
    // ..and assign point 4 (X axis) on polygon 3 to be equal to point 3 on polygon 2 so they are connected also
    poly3PointsArr[6] = poly2PointsArr[4];

    // Update Y axis and also assign that to a point on the second poly so they are connected
    poly1PointPair1Arr[1] = Math.random() * (0.36 - 0.32) + 0.32;
    // ..and also assign that to a point on the second poly so they are connected
    poly2PointsArr[3] = poly1PointPair1Arr[1];
    poly2PointsArr[5] = Math.random() * (0.73 - 0.66) + 0.66;
    // ..and assign point 4 (Y axis) on polygon 3 to be equal to point 3 on polygon 2 so they are connected also
    poly3PointsArr[7] = poly2PointsArr[5];

    // Throw the updated coordinates back into their respective attribute arrays
    poly1PointsArr[0] = poly1PointPair1Arr.join();

    // Convert modified array of points back to string, and update var
    poly1Points = poly1PointsArr.join();
    poly2Points = poly2PointsArr.join();
    poly3Points = poly3PointsArr.join();

    // Update the 'to' attribute with the new values
    poly1Anim.setAttribute('to', poly1PointsArr);
    poly2Anim.setAttribute('to', poly2Points);
    poly3Anim.setAttribute('to', poly3Points);

    // Play the animation!
    poly1Anim.beginElement();
    poly2Anim.beginElement();
    poly3Anim.beginElement();

    resetPoints = setTimeout(function() {

      poly1.setAttribute('points', poly1PointsArr);
      poly2.setAttribute('points', poly2Points);
      poly3.setAttribute('points', poly3Points);

    }, 600);
  },
};

animPoints.init();

var scrollTimer = -1;
```

Comment: I don't have a  solution, but this is not how `clipPath` is usually used. It normally is defined in the `defs` section and then referenced on the elements to be clipped via the `clip-path` attribute or it is defined as a child of the to-be-clipped element, see [the examples here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath). Having `clipPath`s as top level elements is at least very unusual. I also wonder why you define the width and height of the SVG as 0.

Comment: @mmlr Thank you for the information. I'm pretty new to working with SVG's so still learning! I have added the `defs` section to the tag, unfortunately this made no difference. As for the height and width, my understanding with the clipping mask is that these two attributes are pretty much redundant in this case, so I guess I could just remove these altogether. Obviously correct me if 'm wrong ;-)